# Remove the clicked objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to remove the array objects that are being clicked and add them into another array to display them else where. I posted the current code.

I think the problem maybe with `.currentTarget`. I tried replacing the .currentTarget to  .target but the function wasn't getting past this line : `if (socket_Array[i] == in_event.target)` (in this version its .currentTarget, I am just saying when I tried changing it to .target)

The error I get is this:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@2c2a8f11 to flash.display.DisplayObject.
```

Function that creates the objects:

```
function createSockets():void
{
       var socket_one:socket = new socket ();
       var socket_two: socketyellow = new socketyellow ();
       var socket_three: socketdarkorange = new socketdarkorange ();
       var socket_four: socketlightgreen= new socketlightgreen ();
       var socket_five: socketpurple = new socketpurple ();
       var socket_six: socketdarkgreen = new socketdarkgreen ();

       socket_Array.push(socket_one, socket_two,socket_three, socket_four, socket_five, socket_six);

       for (var i:int=0; i<socket_Array.length; i++)
       {
               addChild(socket_Array[i]);
               socket_Array [i].x = socket_x_position;
               socket_Array [i].y = socket_y_position;
               socket_Array[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, removeItemOnClick);
       }
                temp_update ();
}
```

Function that is suppose to get rid of the object clicked and add it to an array.

```
  function removeItemOnClick(in_event:MouseEvent):void
    {


    var i:int = 0;
    for (i=0; i<socket_Array.length; i++)
    {

    if (socket_Array[i] == in_event.currentTarget)
    {

    trace ("it goes here");
    var removed = socket_Array.splice(i, 1);
    trace (removed);
    trace (socket_Array );
    var drop:Sprite = in_event.currentTarget as Sprite;
    removeChild (drop);
    removedItem[removedItem.length] = removed;
    createremovedItem ();
    trace (removedItem);
    updateDisplay ();
    choice_updateDisplay ();

    }

    }

    }
    var removedItem_position = 0
    function createremovedItem () {
        for (removedItem_position; removedItem_position<removedItem.length; removedItem_position++){
            addChild (removedItem [removedItem_position]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, .currentTarget is correct.

Secondly, there's no point in calling removeChild() and then calling addChild(). The net effect of both calls is nothing.

Almost all of the code in the second function is unnecessary. Here's a shorter version:

```
function removeItemOnClick(in_event:MouseEvent):void {
    var index:int = socket_Array.indexOf(in_event.currentTarget);
    var drop:Sprite = socket_Array.splice(index,1) as Sprite;
    removedItem.push(drop);
    updateDisplay();
    choice_updateDisplay();
}
```

If you want to display the new item elsewhere, just change drop.x and drop.y.

Comment: if i do that, i get a problem, first of all without removeChild the object doesn't disappear completely, the first one works fine but the ones after sort of glitch. I tried the code it works fine thank you. but can u please tell me how can I ask them to change the x and y properly, I did that right now but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests it looks like it is problem with type coercion.

Try to replace the condition of your if statement with this:

```
    if (DisplayObject(socket_Array[i]) == DisplayObject(in_event.currentTarget))
```

In case this is not working your might have more information while debugging by storing the two objects you want to compare into temporary variables